# Incomprehensible KeyErrors

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm analysing purchase data now with Python (Jupyter Notebook)
I have some daunting issues now, but the worst one is key errors.
They suddenly occurred even though I didn't change any codes about keys.
Sometimes codes work, other times don't, and I wanna know why.

I've been researching on it, but it doesn't seem that there's not appropriate solutions for this problem on the Internet.

For example, I got

```py
df.keys()
```

out → Index(['id',,,,,,,,,,,,,})

```py
df.groupby('id').first()
```

The problem that came up is 'KeyError': 'id'

It used to show the first row of id in the entire data frame, but all of a sudden it started showing me the error instead of the data frame.
(Although I double-checked if the data frame has the key.....)

Comment: No no no don't do `keys`, what does `print('id' in df.columns)` output?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

'id' is a string, not a Dataframe Column, you should write like this:

```
df.groupby(['id'])
```

Comment: Sorry but with the brackets and without the brackets are equivalent, yes `id` is a string, also could be a dataframe column, this is wrong!